# Can I make a configurable typedef struct in System Verilog?

Tags: fpga, verilog, system-verilog

In order to optimize design, I want to make a struct like this:

```
typedef struct {
  logic a1;
  logic a2;

  generate if (CFG == CFG_B) begin
    logic b1; 
    logic b2;
  end endgenerate
} my_struct
```

or I also tried:

```
generate if (CFG == CFG_A) begin 
  typedef struct {
  < a1, a2>
  } my_struct
end endgenerate

generate if (CFG == CFG_B) begin 
  typedef struct {
  < a1, a2, b1, b2>
  } my_struct
end endgenerate
```

I want to have structure with fields [a1, a2] in CFG_A; [a1, a2, b1, b2] in CFG_B.

Showed code doesn't work (this was predictable..), I have no more ideas how to describe this struct.

Comment: You can manipulate using three macros CFG, CFG_A and CFG_B instead of parameters and use `ifdef`

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this in synthesizable SystemVerilog. I assume you tagged this [fpga](/questions/tagged/fpga) to be synthesized into an FPGA, otherwise I would have recommended using classes instead.

The closest thing you can to do is create two different struct types and pass on of them as a type parameter to a module. But when you pass the CFG_A struct into the module, that module could not contain any references to `b1` or `b2`. You would have the same problem with the approach you attempted.

You might want to look at the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info) and see if you can create another question with the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of ways you can work around the problem:

1. use conditional compilation with `` `ifdef ``, which can become ugly, but commonly used

```
typedef struct {
  logic a1;
  logic a2;

`ifdef CFG_A // of course, CFG_A must be a macro as well.
    logic b1; 
    logic b2;
`endif
} my_struct
```

2. you can use a typedef parameter in verilog to pass a correct type to the module.

```
module my_cfg #(type my_struct=int)();
   my_struct a,b,c;
   // do something here with the vars.
endmodule

module top;
  typedef struct {
    logic a1, a2;
  } type1;
  
  typedef struct {
    logic a1, a2, b1, b2;
  } type2;
  
  if (cfg == CFG_A) 
    my_cfg #(type1) c();
  else
    my_cfg #(type2) c();
endmodule
```